# Why is this variable appearing as undefined?

Tags: batch-file, dictionary, drive

I have this code:

```
FOR %%d IN (c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z) do (
        IF NOT EXIST %%d:\ (
            echo Free drive %%d
            set D=%%d:
        )
)

echo d=%D%
echo Using %D% to map remote drive
subst %D% /d
subst %D% \\path_to_drive
```

and after this I'm using the `D` variable to map a free drive. The thing is, when I first run this, and try to map the drive, the script thinks that the D variable is undefined, or contains nothing. If I print it's value when the script ends, with:

```
set D
```

I see that it found a drive, and it got it's value. When I run the script a second time, it will work as expected. It drives me crazy that batch thinks the variable is undefined, and after the script finishes it's execution it has a value. I'd also like to add that this is the only part where the `D` variable is used, and that there will `ALWAYS` be at least one free drive, so, the fact that no drives are available isn't true.

EDIT: I've added the lines that I use to map the drive.

Comment: "the script thinks that the D variable is undefined": how do you determine this?

Comment: I suspect that `%D%` yields an empty string :-)

Comment: The lines below the `for` are : `echo d=%D%` and `subst %D% \\path_to_drive`, and I get a `d=` and `Invalid parameter - \\path_to_drive` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on *where* exactly you use the environment variable this may happen. Keep in mind that cmd expands environment variables in the parsing state of a command. And any command that has a parenthesized block is a single, large command itself. So what you posted above is one command and any environment variables are expanded immediately when cmd *reads* it, instead of when it's executed.

To circumvent this, try putting a

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion enableextensions
```

at the top of your batch file and use the environment variable with `!D!` instead of `%D%`.

Comment: I'm using this variable a couple of lines below to do a `subst`. Will I need to change every variable in the script from `%` to `!` ?

Comment: You can try. It'd help if you posted your complete script in the question or at least the complete part that exhibits the problem. But changing `%` to `!` for the offending variable should be enough.

Comment: I still wonder why it didn't work in the first place. You didn't have yet another block around all this, right?

Comment: Yes, definitely. Every statement "block" within parentheses is a single command which will first be read and parsed and in that stage all environment variables will already be replaced (except when you use `!` and delayed expansion.

Comment: I will keep that in mind for future use. Thank you very much! I don't know how I would have pulled that off without your help :)

Answer (score 1):

This works for me, can you see if it works for you on your setup, can you also show us how you reference D?

```
FOR %%d IN (c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z) do (
        IF NOT EXIST %%d:\ (
                echo Free drive %%d
                set D=%%d:
        )
)
echo %D%
```